# Wordpress gallery colorbox display only one thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, gallery, colorbox, wordpress-3.5

I want to insert a gallery into a wordpress post so that I can have multiple images but only display one thumbnail.

I am using Wordpress 3.5, the Gallery shortcode and colorbox.

any ideas?

Comment: A quick and dirty hack;
`code`.gallery-item {
 display: none;
 
}
.gallery-item:first-child {
 display:block;
}`code`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my [pro tip on coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/yc15ng?i=1&p=1&q=&t%5B%5D=%21%21mine&t%5B%5D=%21%21bookmarks). I use pages/post to store images and display a gallery with the shortcode.